# Looking a instance's class hierarchy in Python

Tags: python, oop, iterator, generator

Taking `zip` for example.
I just want to know is it an `Iterable` or `Iterator` or `Generator` .

so I put this:

```
zip(x,y).__class__
```

it prints: zip
Why class name are lowercase?

```
import inspect
inspect.getmro(zip) 
zip.__base__
```

It prints: (zip, object)
That's impossible. Python doc says `zip` returns an `iterator` (or `generator`?), but `zip` apparently is not inherited from Iterator or alikes according what `getmro` prints.

So the two questions ,thanks for help.

Comment: They're ABC's, they don't appear in the MRO of a builtin object...

Comment: Anything can be an iterator. It doesn't have to inherit from any particular base type; it just has to provide the right methods.

Comment: Python places much less emphasis on what type an object is, it cares about what the object can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in Python inherits from `Iterator` or `Iterable`, as they embody a *protocol*. Python looks for the [`__iter__` and `__next__` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), not for a specific base class. Any object can be an iterable or iterator, simply by implementing those methods.

`zip()` is a built-in function defined in C code, and it follows the naming convention for all built-ins; these are always in lowercase; the type it returns is not all that relevant here and follows the function name.

The [`collections.abc.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) and [`collections.abc.Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) classes are *abstract base classes*; they implement [special hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) that essentially return `True` if the instance or subclass against which you are test implement the required methods.

`zip()` is both an iterable (it has an `__iter__` method) and an iterator (`__iter__` returns the object itself and it has a `__next__` method):

```
>>> from collections.abc import Iterator, Iterable
>>> zip_instance = zip('')
>>> type(zip_instance)
<class 'zip'>
>>> isinstance(zip_instance, Iterator)
True
>>> isinstance((zip_instance, Iterable)
True
>>> zip_instance.__iter__
<method-wrapper '__iter__' of zip object at 0x10f2d8348>
>>> zip_instance.__iter__() is zip_instance
True
>>> zip_instance.__next__
<method-wrapper '__next__' of zip object at 0x10f2d8348>
```

`zip()` is not a generator, as it doesn't have any of the [special generator methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods):

```
>>> hasattr(zip_instance, 'send')
False
>>> hasattr(zip_instance, 'throw')
False
>>> hasattr(zip_instance, 'close')
False
```

Comment: A note on `zip` instead of `Zip`: that's just how a lot of built-in types work; Python and the standard library only conform to PEP8 to a certain degree.

Comment: @chepner: PEP8 states that the current conventions of the project should be honoured, and in CPython all built-ins are lowercase. So `zip()` is lowercase for that reason, mostly.

Comment: More importantly, the actual type of the thing returned by zip() is irrelevant.  No one ever looks at that class.  zip() is lower-case because it is used as a function.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: clarified the remark a little to add that.

Comment: But in python doc the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function def is using `yields`. Isn't function that using `yield` always a `generator`?

Comment: I'm confused because I am sure that python doc says :[Any function containing a yield keyword is a generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators)

Comment: @WeiChing: you are confusing the Python expression with the verb. `zip()` *yields* (verb), but it doesn't use a *`yield` expression* to do so. You use the latter to *yield* (verb), which creates a generator function, but not all iterators that *yield* (verb) values use the expression.

Comment: @WeiChing: you could also build an `iterator` in Python code that only uses `__next__` and no `yield` expression, yet every time you call the `__next__` method Python expects it to produce (or *yield*, the verb again) another value in the iteration or raise `StopIteration`.